# Testing my models method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have to test the creation of my `account`. This is my `Account.create()` in controllers method.

```
Account.create( account: { name: "#{params[:account][:name]}", 
    description: "#{params[:description]}" }, user: { email: current_user.name })
```

I have to test my `model method` Account.create().

```
post :create, '/account'
```

Below is my **spec** class.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Account do
  before(:all) do

  end

  it "can create an account" do
    FactoryGirl.create :account, name: "something", description: "something"
    # Account.create()
  end

end
```

I am not sure on how to procced.

Answer (score 1):

Please, take a look at [this](http://everydayrails.com/2012/03/19/testing-series-rspec-models-factory-girl.html) article, it explains how to test Models. 
I your case it should be like this:

```
it "can create an account" do
  FactoryGirl.create(:account, name: "something", description: "something").should be_valid

end
```

Comment: **Don't** put a space between method name and opening parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

FactoryGirl is a tool to use when the methods you want to test need a complicated predefined state. When account creation has no dependencies you could simply do something like:

```
it "can create an account" do
  acc = Account.create(name: 'something', description:'something')

  acc.name.should == 'something'
  acc.description.should == 'something'
end
```

Comment: acc = Account.create(name: 'something', description:'something'). Instead of this if i have to use FactoryGirl... how would i go about it.

Comment: You can replace Account.create(...) with FactoryGirl.create(:account, ...). Both should return an Account object. The difference is, with FactoryGirl you have to define the factory somewhere.

Comment: Can you help me in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25157776/how-to-test-my-post-request-for-project-creation-project-create am i doing the right thing... i have to use the FactoryGirl